# WPF Tab Control: How do I get the currently selected tab?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabcontrol, selecteditem

In my tab SelectionChanged event (is this the correct event, I can't find a tab changed event?), how do I access the new tab?

Also from outside this event in normal code, how do I access the currently selected tab?

```
  TabControl.SelectionChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler(TabControl_SelectionChanged);

  void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      //How so access my currently selected tab???
  }
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`TabControl.SelectedItem` is the selected tab.

cast it to a `TabItem` to get the properties.

What I mostly do is bind it to a viewmodel.

Comment: TabControl.SelectedItem is actually not the TabItem but its view model.

Answer (score 23):

you can use the `TabControl.SelectedItem` property, it will get you the selected `TabItem`

Sample shown below

```
TabItem ti = Tabs1.SelectedItem as TabItem;
MessageBox.Show("This is " + ti.Header + " tab");
```

Answer (score 14):

`TabControl.SelectedIndex` gets you the currently selected tab index in [version 3.0 and later of the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`TabControl.SelectedContent` gives you the selected `TabItem` (read only)

`TabControl.SelectedItem` gives you the view model of the selected `TabItem`.

`TabControl.SelectedIndex` gives you the index of the selected `TabItem`, which can be bound to the `ObservableCollection<ViewModels>`'s index, when `TabControl.ItemsSource` is bound to it.