# How to find the current/active Tab in Josh Smith's MVVM Demo App

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I've been adapting [Josh Smith's MVVM Demo app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) to suit my requirements.

I have been successful for most part of it. Now I want to add a feature "Print"(similar to a print feature that exsits in any application) in the file menu item for this applicaiton. Since I can open multiple tabs in this application, how will I know which tab(to be more specific which Workspace) was active when the user clicked the "Print"? The code below shows the DataTemplate where the TabControl is used in the DemoApp.

Any help/thoughts are greatly appreciated.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
<TabControl 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
  Margin="4"
  />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255017/wpf-tab-control-how-do-i-get-the-currently-selected-tab

Comment: @devhedgehog : No this is not how things work in MVVM. MVVM does not have code behind, the stakoverflow link that you suggest works for general WPF solutions.

Comment: Where did you read that? model-VIEW-ViewModel pattern sure allows code behind my friend code behind is part of the VIEW. Futhermore if you check out that link properly the user binds TabControl.SelectedItem to a property in ViewModel. There is no code behind at all there :)

Comment: But the stackoverflow link does not work for MVVM architecture! I did try out the first answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857184/wpf-tab-control-and-mvvm-selection, but it does not work for me.

Comment: SelectedIndex is not working for you and also SelectedItem? Well then your ViewModel needs improvements. Post more code please

Comment: @devhedgehog Can we continue this conversation in a chat please?

Comment: @devhedgehog I work in the Pacific time zone, I am not sure about you. Also I do not have sufficient reputation to invite you to chat in SO.

Comment: Run your code and check output window. I think there you will stumble upon few binding errors

Comment: @devhedgehog In JoshSmith's MvvmDemoApp example let us say there is a print option in the File menuItem in the MainWindow, which prints the current active tab. How do I do that?

Comment: Just check that guys code if you already have his example :) :) :)

Comment: @devhedgehog he does not have this feature implemented!

Comment: I found this example using google :) try it out https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Printing-Overview-f28c541a

Answer (score 0):

First of all your DataContext is wrong, your DataContext should be a ViewModel, to which you bind the ItemsSource to a ObservableCollection Property. E.g.

```
<TabControl 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" 
  SelectedItem={Binding SelectedTab}
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
  Margin="4"
  />
```

Where you have

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs { get; set; }
    public TabViewModel SelectedTab { get; set; }
}
```

And in your window code behind, all you should have in the constructor is

```
public MainView()
{
    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel()
}
```

or

```
public MainView(MainViewModel vm)
{
    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

Comment: This is code is from Josh Smith's example, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx . It works fine, just that I am unable to get the active tab. When I try your approach, nothing is shown in the tab.